# Swift parse JSON with variable types

Tags: ios, json, swift, serialization

I have JSON data serialized as NSDictionary type, for instance

```
{ data = 0; } // "data":"0" (when I see its value in debugger)
```

or

```
{ data = 1; }  //"data": Int64(1)(when I see its value in debugger)
```

I m trying to access this data as:

```
 json["data"] as! Int
```

, but sometimes it cannot be parsed as Integer, because if its 0 it has String value, and I get error:

```
 Could not cast value of type 'NSTaggedPointerString' (0x109b54b90) to 'NSNumber'
```

What is wrong, and how can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conditionals to the rescue!

```
let data: Int = json["data"] as? Int ?? 0
```

If the the value for the `"data"` key is missing or `"0"` the `data` it will be set to zero.

Answer (score 0):

For a good answer, you'll need to post more context as to what code led to those 2 values is the debugger. It's odd that 0's yield strings, but other numbers yield ints.

Here's a solution to the immediate problem:

```
let x = json["data"]
let y = x as? Int ?? Int(y as! String)!
```

This will first (safely) try to cast to `Int`. If that fails, it'll force cast to a `String`, then run that through the `Int` initializer so it can be parsed.